# Edge selection does not result in highlighted edge for one object in scene

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I have an object in my scene where selecting an edge does not display the edge with a different color.

[image: no highlighting]

Why?

Here is an object, in the same scene, where edge selection highlights as expected.

[image: working edge highlighting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had removed doubles, I got the selection highlighting back.

Now, why would that change anything?

Comment: Most likely the reason was that there were double vertices composing several versions of that edge. With that, Blender couldn't display selected edge as highlighted because there were some more edges in front of it. Anyway the first thing to check is to remove doubles.

Comment: Talking about doubles, I wish there was a way to select for instance a vertex and delete it together with all its doubles with one keypress.

Comment: You can press Ctrl+L while vertex is selected and the geometry linked to that vertex will be selected as well.

Comment: Thats seems like a promising answer, thanks!